# gremlin where clause with property and traversal sum

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

sample graph:

```
g.addV('location').property('name','Location A').as('location')
.addV('building').property('totalLetterCapacity',50).as('building')
.sideEffect(addE('has-building').from('location'))
.addV('letter').property('totalLetters',10).as('a')
.sideEffect(addE('has-letter').from('building'))
.addV('letter').property('totalLetters',10).as('b')
.sideEffect(addE('has-letter').from('building'))
.addV('letter').property('totalLetters',10).as('c')
.sideEffect(addE('has-letter').from('building'))
.addV('letter').property('totalLetters',10).as('d')
.sideEffect(addE('has-letter').from('building'))
.addV('letter').property('totalLetters',10).as('e')
.sideEffect(addE('has-letter').from('building'))
```

In this sample graph, I want to get all buildings that are full with letters.  So in this sample graph there is only one location which does fulfill the requirement - has 50 total letter capacity and 5 letters with 10 capacity attached to the building.

I was hoping something like this would work:

```
g.V().hasLabel('location')
 .out('has-building')
 .where(values('totalLetterCapacity')
       .is(eq(out('has-letter').values('totalLetters').sum())
```

but it seems like the eq predicate or any of the predicates (lte,lt, gte)  does not allow for traversals.  I tried doing some kind of double where clause - a where within a where, but ended up getting a bit crazy.

I'm using azure cosmos db gremlin.  what's the correct way to use a property in the traversal as a sum comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`P.eq()` is a test of equality so something like this:

```
values('totalLetterCapacity').is(eq(out('has-letter').values('totalLetters').sum())
```

is saying that you want to compare the numeric value in "totalLetterCapacity" to an anonymous `Traversal` (not the result of that `Traversal`) which is obviously `false`.

The approach to solving this one that immediately jumped into my mind was to do this:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('location').
......1>   out('has-building').as('a').
......2>   where('a', eq('a')).
......3>     by('totalLetterCapacity').
......4>     by(out('has-letter').values('totalLetters').sum())
==>v[2]
```

Above, `where()` compares the vertex labelled "a" to the vertex labelled "a" with `P.eq()` but the value assigned in that comparison is determined by the supplied `by()` modulators. The first "a" is the "totalLetterCapacity" and the second "a" is the `sum()` of the "totalLetters" on the "letter" vertices.